# Multi-target library works fine with SPM, but fails with “no such module” when built with CocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

I’m adding CocoaPods support to a Swift library previously available only via SPM. The library consists of two targets, one of which depends on the other.

In `MyLibrary`’s source files, I `import MyLibraryProtocols`, and it works just fine when the library’s integrated using SPM. However, validation of the CocoaPods podspec (`pod spec lint`) fails with the following error:

```
- ERROR | [MyLibrary/MyLibrary] xcodebuild:  MyLibrary/Sources/MyLibrary/<REDACTED>.swift:9:8: error: no such module 'MyLibraryProtocols'
```

It seems that separate subspecs, when integrated and built, end up in a single target, so an explicit `import` is not needed and, moreover, not supported. (I may be mistaken about that, as I’m not a CocoaPods expert.) If I removed the `import`, the library would unsuprisingly stop working with SPM.

**How do I keep my code in separate targets, one of which depends on the other, and add support for CocoaPods?**

Here’s the way targets / subspecs are declared, for reference:

```swift
targets: [
    .target(
        name: "MyLibrary",
        dependencies: ["MyLibraryProtocols"]
    ),
    .target(name: "MyLibraryProtocols"),
]
```

```rb
s.default_subspec = "MyLibrary"

s.subspec "MyLibrary" do |library|
  library.source_files = "Sources/MyLibrary/**/*.{swift}"
  library.dependency "MyLibrary/MyLibraryProtocols"
end

s.subspec "MyLibraryProtocols" do |protocols|
  protocols.source_files = "Sources/MyLibraryProtocols/**/*.{swift}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution I’ve found so far is to explicitly check whether the library is built using CocoaPods, with a compiler directive, and only include the `import`s if it’s not:

```swift
#if !COCOAPODS
import MyLibraryProtocols
#endif
```

The `COCOAPODS` flag is added to the build automatically.